# Properties of continuous martingale

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $X_t$ be a continuous martingale on $\mathbb{R}.$ From continuity we have that $X_t$ is uniformly continuous on closed interval let's say $[0,t]$. Uniformly continuous function on some set is bounded. Is't also true for $X_t$? I mean,
\begin{equation}
\forall \omega \sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} |X_t(\omega)| < M.
\end{equation}

For example if I assume that $X_t$ is a standard Brownian motion then $X_t \sim N(0,t)$ and of course $X_t$ is unbounded. But from my reasoning above it's should be.

I would really appreciate any hints or tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careful, your inequality should be:

$$\sup_{0 \leq s \leq t} |X_t (\omega )| < M_\omega$$

That is, by continuity, each sample path can be bounded on compact intervals, with the bound $M_\omega$ depending on each sample path. This does not imply that the entire process is bounded. As you mentioned, Brownian motion is a counterexample to this claim.